# How to read uwsgi stats output

Tags: uwsgi, uwsgi-stats-server

I'm on this page http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/StatsServer.html and using [uwsgitop](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgitop) but I have no idea how to interpret the output. The docs aren't giving too much away too. So how would one go about understanding this:

[image]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

WID -> worker id

% -> percentage of served requests by the worker

PID -> process id of the worker

REQ -> number of managed requests

RPS -> number of current requests handled per second

EXC -> number of raised exceptions

SIG -> number of managed uwsgi signals (NOT unix signals !!!)

STATUS -> can be idle, busy, pause, cheaped or sig

AVG -> average response time for the worker

RSS -> RSS memory (need --memory-report)

VSZ -> address space (need --memory-report)

TX -> transmitted data

RunT -> running time

Comment: awesome. specifically, what does 'number of managed requests' mean? does it mean current requests? Does AVG mean average response time for each request?

Comment: +1 thanks. Would be good if you could like to some official docs... if they exist.

Comment: Where did you find this description? I'm also interested in what @super9 is asking. It seems the numer in the `REQ` column keeps going up for me, is this normal or not?

Comment: I understood REQ as the number of *treated* requests since the server started. It would thus be normal only to see these number grow.

Comment: This was immensely helpful, thank you.

Below all workers, there's an "M" with a digit to its left, and then a large number to its right. Am I right to think the number on the right is the total memory usage? And any idea what the number to the left might be?

Comment: this needs to be updated. Now there are many other values in uwsgitop.

Comment: @gitaarik - Field descriptions here:
https://github.com/xrmx/uwsgitop

Answer (score 28):

As I can not yet comment (due to reputation) for anyone who is wondering how to see the RSS/VSZ values you need to set --memory-report in your uwsgi configuration, not when you execute uwsgitop.

See http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#memory-report

Comment: We usually recommend to wait until you have the reputation to post a comment, but since your answer at least has some substance I'll leave it up.  Welcome to the community, @alexhayes.